# Creating a Catch for the error: External entry point

Tags: apex, trigger

There is validation that I made but not using a Validation Rule.

Entries with the same Product Name within its Parent Object will be prevented. So for example, a user cannot input 2 ProductA within the Company.

I created this by creating a **UNIQUE text field**, and have a WF populate this using the LookupID+ProductName.

I already have an existing catch for custom validations, any ideas on how would I insert a catch for this?

```
<apex:commandButton styleClass="slds-button slds-button_brand slds-m-top_large"
    value="Save" action="{!saveRevenueSchedules}" status="status" reRender="errormsg" >
</apex:commandButton>

public void Product(){
   try {
    upsert revenueSchedules;
    }
    catch(System.DmlException e) {
   String S1 = e.getMessage();
        S1 = S1.substringBetween('FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, ' , ': [');
       ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,S1 )); 
    }
}
```

Any kind of help is much appreciated

Error Message: **Argument 2 cannot be null
Error is in expression '{!saveRevenueSchedules}' in component  in page opportunityschedulepage: External entry point**

End Goal: Have an error Pop-up saying "Invalid Input"

Comment: What is happening now when you try to save a record that would produce a non-unique value for the text field, and how do you want it to be different?

Comment: @ThomasTaylor already updated my post. When I save the record with a non-unique the error above shows.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the relevant code from the VF page and the controller.

Comment: @DavidCheng the code is properly working if I don't have the unique text field that I created, but I needed that to avoid duplicate entries from user since VR is not an option.

Comment: the error is in action method `saveRevenueSchedules` which you did not include in OP. Use [edit]